# Porting Mongoose Web Server to VxWorks

Tags: webserver, rpc, porting, vxworks, mongoose-web-server

I need a web server in my VxWorks application to show a web page supporting RPC (ex. JSON-RPC). I think Mongoose Web Server (https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) would be the perfect candidate for this, but it is unfortunately incompatible with VxWorks.

If I want to port it to VxWorks, where should I start? Is there anyone out there with experience with this, and if so, please point me in the right direction.

Also; if any one knows a better solution for VxWorks please let me know.

I am using Workbench 3.2, VxWorks 6.5.

Best regards,
EuxOn

Comment: I got a webserver to work on VxWorks about 5 years ago. Unfortunately I no longer have access to my e-mail or any code from that job, and I forget all the details (including which webserver I ported). But I do know that I just went at it with a mad compile/fix/repeat cycle until it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Porting work starts from compiling the code and looking at compilation errors if any. VxWorks has GCC toolchain, so this command would do well to start:

```
gcc -c mongoose.c
```

Mongoose works on virtually any POSIX system, I don't expect VxWorks being an exception.